# Is it possibile to create Nautilus custom column generated by script?

Tags: scripts, nautilus, nautilus-actions, nautilus-script, nautilus-extensions

Is there any possibility to add a custom (my own) column to nautilus folder view?
Content of that column would be generated by script.

For example, I have got an additional information about specific files in a database (let's say SQLight). I want to see this information in the additional column. Script will search information about the file in data base and if find something, show it in the file row in the column.

I think this requires to run a script when nautilus generate a folder view.

I found, it's possibile to create scripts which could be run in the right-click menu, but if it's possible to create scripts run when a folder view is being generated?

Sorry for my English. If something is hard to understand, pleas inquire.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? Thanks